# How to know if the site is running on Drupal? what are the mark-up patterns?

Tags: drupal, content-management-system

I'm wondering what is the markup pattern of DRUPAL. I know that the site is running in Wordpress when I view it's mark-up and see /wp-themes, or in Joomla it uses /templates /administrator (for admin page eg. site.com/administrator).

Comment: Just curious here - why do you want to know that?

Comment: Good question - why does he want to know that?   Must be white hat, though, coz a 7334 uber-h4x0r would just install Drupal on his own box (in a VM, of course) & see for himself

Comment: I'm doing some research on how many sites I know is powered by Drupal. I just discovered that many also use Expression Engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me the fatest way is to check for the drupal.js in the source or the `Drupal` global js variable using a js console like firebug.

Answer (score 2):

Try to go to update.php. You should see Access Denied and a blueish theme, which is Garland.

Also you can go to /user and recognize that it's a Drupal login. Wordpress goes to /wp-login and Joomla goes to /administer.

Answer (score 1):

All of the other answers work, plus - if they have css and js optimisation turned on you might see links to the css and js files similar to this (with "sites/default/files"):

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="/sites/default/files/css/css_b4e7deec9864f332efab3b64ea4fa606.css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Drupal sets the HTTP Expires header to Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT, which is Dries' birthday. Find that in includes/bootstrap.inc, function drupal_page_header().

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I look for..

Most drupal sites use "clean" urls  so the admin page is usually  http://www.site.com/admin

Answer (score 0):

In the source code you can find

jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings,-----------Code-----------------)

and also you can find as JS files

script type="text/javascript" src="/examplesite/sites/all/modules/XXXXX/js/XXX.js?g"

and css files as

link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/examplesite/sites/all/modules/xxxxx/demo.css?g"

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the license:

http://www.isthissitedrupal.org/LICENSE.txt

Answer (score 0):

Looking for paths of theme or javascript files won't work if they are cached.

You as well as the license, might be able to find CHANGELOG.txt, UPGRADE.txt or MAINTAINERS.txt in the web root.

Depending on how the server is set up, you also could request the paths set to access denied in .htaccess.

If you get access denied rather than page not found on all those patterns, it's very likely to be Drupal. These paths are (prepend the web root): module, profile, themes etc. See the .htaccess file for Drupal. If you get page not found for these pages, it still could be Drupal.